# css hacks and rewriting them

Tags: css

I've stopped using CSS hacks for different browsers and instead favour the "conditional comments adding classes to html tag" approach.

Which brings me to my question. How would I write this ie8 hack *without the hack*?

`.grab-cursor{cursor:move\0/;}`

I'm looking to implement:

`.ie8 .grab-cursor{`--non hacked code here-- `;}`

(I never really understood css hacks so I'm glad not to have to use them now!)

Comment: `style: property \0/;` is a rule that gets interpreted only by Internet Explorer 8 and 9. `*style: property;` would be the corresponding hack for Internet Explorer 6 and 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.grab-cursor{cursor:move;}
```

You really don't need any hack or comment here, it should work pretty well across all browsers (see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html). What exactly is the issue you are trying to solve?

**EDIT**

To answer the general question of how to apply certain styles to certain versions of IE without hacks, if you use the conditional comment block

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

you have various possibilities.

If you just want to fix a general Internet Explorer problem, you can use

```
 .oldie .grab-cursor {
     /*IE-tailored css styles without the hack*/
 }
```

and you're set. If you want to fix something just for, let's say IE7, you can use

```
 .ie7 .grab-cursor {
     /*IE-tailored css styles without the hack*/
 }
```

but the best way to fix certain problems would be to use modernizr ( http://www.modernizr.com/ ), so you can do stuff like

```
/* style I'm currently using in production */
.cssgradients #main nav{
    background: linear-gradient(left, black, #e00, black);
}

.no-cssgradients nav{
    background: url(../img/nav-bg.png) center center repeat-y; /*image background as fallback */
}
```

I would also recommend http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/, as it allows you to have

```
background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #000000 49%,#8f0222 49%,#6d0019 100%);
```

instead of

```
background: #000000; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #000000 49%, #8f0222 49%, #6d0019 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(49%,#000000), color-stop(49%,#8f0222), color-stop(100%,#6d0019)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #000000 49%,#8f0222 49%,#6d0019 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #000000 49%,#8f0222 49%,#6d0019 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #000000 49%,#8f0222 49%,#6d0019 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #000000 49%,#8f0222 49%,#6d0019 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#6d0019',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

Comment: Thanks, I use the conditional comments block and modernizer already but never knew about Prefix Free!